# How to merge multiple files into one line by line?

Tags: linux, merge, vi

I have 4 files

```
**File1**          **File2**        **File3**        **File4**
alpha              this             security         rain 
beta               that             performance      go 
gamma              an               auto             away
.                  .                .                .    
.                  .                .                .
.                  .                .                .
[25000 rows]       [25000 rows]     [25000 rows]     [25000 rows]
```

I want these 4 files to be combined together in the resultfile as
ResultFile

```
alpha
this
security
rain
beta
that
performance
go
.
.
.
[75000 rows]
```

how can I do that in vi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paste`:

```
paste -d "\n" file1 file2 file3 file4
```